# OpenCV Python cv2.BackgroundSubtractor parameters

Tags: python, opencv, parameters, background-subtraction

### Summary

It seems like changing the parametes of BackgroundSubtractorMOG doesn't affect the results of the algorithm.

I'm usign Python: 2.7.6 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)
OpenCV: '2.4.10'
OS: Windows 7 x64

The default parameters for the algorithm are:

```
history=200, nmixtures=5, backgroundRatio=0.7
```

So, creating the background subtractor with different parameters should give different results. But I always get the same result (foreground mask) with default parameters and with custom parameters.

---

### Reproducing the problem

First, Create two background subtractor objects with different parameters:

```
bg1 = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()
bg2 = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG(history=3, nmixtures=5, backgroundRatio=0.0001)
```

Create 2 "VideoCaptrue" objects:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture('different_video.mp4')
```

Test the results:

```
# Get a frame from the first capturing object:
frame = cap.read()[1]

# Get the foreground mask from both background subtractors:
fg1 = bg1.apply(frame)
fg2 = bg2.apply(frame)

# Show both results and the difference between them:
cv2.imshow('Window name', np.hstack((fg1, fg2, fg1 - fg2)))
cv2.waitKey(30)
```

After running that block of code for some frames, the window shows results from the first background subtractor, results from the second and the difference of the two.

Because both masks are the same, the result of their difference (the third pane) is a full black frame:

[image: 2 BackgroundSubtractorMOG and difference]

Then, suddenly change the source of the video (the second VideoCapture object):

```
# Get a frame from the second capturing object:
frame = cap2.read()[1]

# Get the foreground mask from both background subtractors:
fg1 = bg1.apply(frame)
fg2 = bg2.apply(frame)

# Show both results and the difference between them:
cv2.imshow('Window name', np.hstack((fg1, fg2, fg1 - fg2)))
cv2.waitKey(30)
```

And after running that block of code for some frames you get:

[image: 2 BackgroundSubtractorMOG and difference with new video]

The two foreground masks look the same, and that's why the third pane is a full black frame.

But after running the last block of code for more than 3 frames the results of the second pane should become blacker again (because of the `history=3` in the creation of the `bg2` object). But both background subtractors keep getting the same results (as shown by the third full black pane).

---

### Alternatives

I have also tried modifying their parameters with:

```
bg2.setInt('history')
```

But I get the same results.

And I always get the paremeters I did "set" (e.g.):

```
>>>bg2.getInt('history')
3
```

---

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that (since some version of OpenCV) when I call the method `apply` from the `BackgroundSubtractorMOG` object, it is using a default `learningRate` parameter set at `0.0`, so the BackgroundSubtractor is not "learning" the new frames, it just sticks to the first frame used.

To avoid it, I have to call the method `apply` with an explicit learningRate parameter, then it works as it worked before.

So after starting the code:

```
bg1 = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
frame = cap.read()[1]
```

...instead of doing:

```
fg1 = bg1.apply(frame)
```

I should do:

```
fg1 = bg1.apply(frame, learningRate=0.001)
```

Comment: I'm using cv2 2.4.11 in Python 2.7. Changing the parameters isn't working for me either. I tried passing learningRate=0.001 when applying the subtractor but that doesn't work.

Do you know what can be wrong here?

Comment: Not sure, but first, you are using and old version of OpenCV. Second, what is your OS? I had lots of problems to make it run on Windows, y had to use Linux in a VirtualBox or a physical machine.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I tried it in a Win7 machine. I guess I am using the version pulled by `conda install opencv`. What would you advise?

Comment: Hmm, I really don't know, I haven't used OpenCV y some months, so I don't know if there could be any latest bug or something. But I can suggest you to pay special attention to the parameters and parameter types of the functions. I had lots of troubles once because the function was expecting a tuple of ndarrays and I was giving it an ndarray of ndarrays, or something similar.

Comment: @Jaqo Did you try other learning rates?  The learning rate 0.001 might just have been too small (or even too large) for your data.

Comment: Setting the learningRate parameter in apply works for me, but setting the history parameter doesn't change anything.  Has anyone had this problem?